# Compare data type values on choice of constructor only

Tags: haskell, types, comparison

I want to compare just the constructor "tag" of a data type.

Is there an easy way to do this?

```
data D = A | B Int | C String
check k d = ?

check A (A) -- True
check B (B 55) -- True
check C (C "xxx") -- True
```

Comment: Ask yourself: which type would `check` have? The first argument is either a value of type `D`, or a function `Int -> D` or a function `String -> D`. Unify those three and... you cannot unify them. So you can't.  However you could do something like `check "A" A = True` pattern matching over the names of the constructors...

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to pattern match a constructor with a wildcard. Like so:

```hs
check :: D -> D -> Bool
check A A = True
check (B _) (B _) = True
check (C _) (C _) = True
check _ _ = False
```

Comment: This is especially nice with record syntax: `check A = True; Check B{} = True; ...`. You don't need to fill in all the blanks for the fields.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few ways to do this, none are perfect.

You can do something similar by comparing the data kind type reps:

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
import Data.Typeable

data D = A | B Int | C Char

kCheck :: Typeable a => Proxy (a::k) -> D -> Bool
kCheck p d = typeRep p == kTypeRep where
  kTypeRep = case d of
    A    -> typeRep (Proxy @ 'A)
    B {} -> typeRep (Proxy @ 'B)
    C {} -> typeRep (Proxy @ 'C)
```

(if you don't have ghc 8.0.1 remove `TypeApplications` and replace `@ 'A` with `:: Proxy 'A`) I think this needs ghc 7.10 (or maybe 7.8 with `AutoDeriveTypeable`).

```
kCheck (Proxy @ 'B) (B 3)
True
kCheck (Proxy @ 'C) A
False
```

---

Or you can use `TemplateHaskell` and compare the `Name`s:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Language.Haskell.TH

data D = A | B Int | C Char

thCheck :: Name -> D -> Bool
thCheck n d = n == conName
  where
    conName = case d of
      A    -> 'A
      B {} -> 'B
      C {} -> 'C

> thCheck 'B (B 3)
True
> thCheck 'A (C 'a')
False
```

---

If you're happy comparing strings you can automatically derive them using `toConstr` from `Data`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Data

data D = A | B Int | C Int
  deriving Data

dCheck :: String -> D -> Bool
dCheck s d = s == show (toConstr d)
```

---

There is a way closest to what you want but this will only work if each type constructor has a distinct type. **So this wouldn't work with with `data D = A Int | B Int` because the type reps of `A` and `B` would both be `Int -> D`**.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Typeable

data D = A | B Int | C String
  deriving Typeable

check :: Typeable a => a -> D -> Bool
check p d = typeOf p == conTypeRep
  where
    conTypeRep = case d of
      A    -> typeOf A
      B {} -> typeOf B
      C {} -> typeOf C
```

Which works as expected:

```
> check B (B 3)
True
> check C A
False
```